# Python: How to get domain\username for logged in user

Tags: python, windows, active-directory

In Python how do I get the logged in username in the domain\username format.  The following just get username:

```py
import getpass
import os

print(os.getlogin())
print(getpass.getuser())
```

Comment: is win or linux needed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go :

```
import os
domain = os.environ['userdomain']
print(domain)
```

(But i see that this doest give the FQDN, but only the NetBIOS name)

Comment: getpass.getuser() + '\\' + os.environ['userdnsdomain']

Comment: @leancz yhea, that gives you averything at once

Answer (score 6):

If you have [`pywin32`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) installed, you can call the corresponding Windows function:

```
import win32api
win32api.GetUserNameEx(win32api.NameSamCompatible)
```

Check out [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724268(v=vs.85).aspx) for other possible parameters and outputs.

Comment: This returns the logon session user name, which should also be available as the `%USERNAME%` and `%USERDOMAIN%` environment variables. This name almost always agrees with the user SID in the process access token, except the 3 common service accounts (i.e. SYSTEM, LOCAL SERVICE, and NETWORK SERVICE) get logged on as the machine name followed by a dollar sign (e.g. "SPAMBOX$"). That may surprise you if you're running as a service using one of those accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Should work in Python 2 and 3

```
import getpass
import platform

print(getpass.getuser()) #username
print(platform.node()) #hostname
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I looked into the source of this function and under the hood it uses `socket.gethostname()`, so you could use that directly to obtain the same info without any extra overhead. The `platform.node()` function goes via `platform.uname()` and gets a few more bits of info that are ultimately discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Does Domain mean hostname? if it is, try this:

```
import socket
socket.getfqdn()
```

Comment: Domainname here represent the Active Directory (or Windows NT for dinosaurs...) domain. It can be different from the host name.

Comment: That returns the domain name of the Computer